# JQM after ajax, popup not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm having problems with my popup after ajax is success, it's not sizing to the center, but on the second time it resizes(because it's already loaded). I tried to follow this [example](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup-dynamic/), but have errors(not popping up). From my code, is it better to do dynamic popup or there is any method that can do like `beforepageshow`, or `load` to show it in the center? For exemple below:

```
//popup
<div data-role="popup" id="popupFood" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
    <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
    <h3>Preferences</h3>
    <div class="ui-block-a" id="foood" style="width:50%"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="someaction()" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>

//ajax success
function food(data, textStatus){
    $('#foood').empty();
        $.each(data, function (i, x) {
            var foodTest = '<label for="grid-checkbox-' + x.id + '">' + x.description+ '</label>' +
            '<input type="checkbox" name="grid-checkbox-' + x.id + '" id="grid-checkbox-' + x.id + '" value="' + x.id + '" data-mini="true" >';
            $('#foood').append(foodTest);
    });
    $('#foood').enhanceWithin(); 
}
```

Comment: popup isn't centered when open?

Comment: No, and when i open it again or go landscape, it centered

Comment: open it programmatically after ajax sucess http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y5X3q/

Comment: I need to test, but only tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center popup by either

- Opening it programmatically after successful Ajax. Note that you need to remove `data-rel="popup"` and set href to `href="#"` on *Anchor* tag.

  ```
  $("#popupFood").popup("open");
  ```
- Reposition it once it's open by listening to `popupafteropen` event and then override position using `reposition` option.

  ```
  $("#popupFood").on("popupafteropen", function () {
    $(this).popup("reposition", {
      positionTo: "window"
    });
  });
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y5X3q/)**